# convert any integer in a textual sentence to string in python

Tags: python, text, nlp

I have a series which looks somewhat like this

```
'0589 BTC: 581 OUTFLOW BANK REF: CUST REF: 0004'
'CUR FR 44F8 Availability: 12,267.24 Debited'
...
```

I would like to replace all the integers/ alpha numeric values to its corresponding word format .

```
For eg.
 0589 --> ZERO FIVE EIGHT NINE
 44F8 --> FOUR FOUR F EIGHT
 12,267.24 --> ONE TWO , TWO SIX SEVEN . TWO FOUR
```

Hence the first item will be converted to

```
'ZERO FIVE EIGHT NINE BTC: FIVE EIGHT ONE OUTFLOW BANK REF: CUST REF: ZERO ZERO ZERO FOUR'
```

and so on .

What is the way to approach this ,

I was looking into some of the python packages like  num2words and inflect but all of them return in human readable format
i.e 22 --> twenty-two which is not fulfilling my requirement

```
conversion_dict = {1:'One' , 2 : 'Two' , 3 : 'Three' , 4 : 'Four' , 5: 'Five' , 6:'Six' , 7 : 'Seven' , 8:'Eight' , 9:'Nine' , 0: 'Zero'}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I have a series?" Does that mean a pandas series (pd.Series)?

Comment: @It_is_Chris ,  Yes series of sentences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# your pandas series
s = pd.Series(['0589 BTC: 581 OUTFLOW BANK REF: CUST REF: 0004', 
               'CUR FR 44F8 Availability: 12,267.24 Debited'], name='Text')
# your conversion dict with strings not ints
conversion_dict = {'1':'One ' , '2' : 'Two ' , '3' : 'Three ' , '4' : 'Four ' ,
                   '5': 'Five ' , '6':'Six ' , '7' : 'Seven ' , '8':'Eight ' ,
                   '9':'Nine ' , '0': 'Zero '}   
# use replace with regex set to true and then replace duplicate spaces between words
s.replace(conversion_dict, regex=True).replace(' +', ' ', regex=True).str.rstrip()

['Zero Five Eight Nine BTC: Five Eight One OUTFLOW BANK REF: CUST REF: Zero Zero Zero Four'
 'CUR FR Four Four FEight Availability: One Two ,Two Six Seven .Two Four Debited']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the string and replace each number by its corresponding string, as i did here:

```py
conversion_dict = {'1':'One' , '2' : 'Two' , '3' : 'Three' , '4' : 'Four' , '5': 'Five' , '6':'Six' , '7' : 'Seven' , '8':'Eight' , '9':'Nine' , '0': 'Zero'}


def parser(string: str):
    def inner():
        for index, char in enumerate(string):
            yield " " + conversion_dict[char] + " " if char.isnumeric() else char

    result = "".join(inner()).lstrip()
    return "".join(s if not (result[i] == result[i - 1] == " ") else "" for i, s in enumerate(result))


string_for_example = """
0589 BTC: 581 OUTFLOW BANK REF: CUST REF: 0004
CUR FR 44F8 Availability: 12,267.24 Debited
"""

print(parser(string_for_example))
```

And the result is:

```
Zero Five Eight Nine BTC: Five Eight One OUTFLOW BANK REF: CUST REF: Zero Zero Zero Four 
CUR FR Four Four F Eight Availability: One Two , Two Six Seven . Two Four Debited
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to give my 2 cents, here is a possible solution to this problem:

```
import re
def num2digit(text):
    mapper = {
        '0': 'ZERO ',
        '1': 'ONE ',
        '2': 'TWO ',
        '3': 'THREE ',
        '4': 'FOUR ',
        '5': 'FIVE ',
        '6': 'SIX ',
        '7': 'SEVEN ',
        '8': 'EIGHT ',
        '9': 'NINE ',
    }
    for k, v in mapper.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(k, v)
    return re.sub(' +', ' ', text).strip()
```

Then you can call it like:

```
>>> num2digit('0589 BTC: 581 OUTFLOW BANK REF: CUST REF: 0004')
'ZERO FIVE EIGHT NINE BTC: FIVE EIGHT ONE OUTFLOW BANK REF: CUST REF: ZERO ZERO ZERO FOUR'
```

To explain what it is doing is to replace every digit with it's mapped name, then add a space after the name to separate each word as desired, then remove possible double whitespaces and then, finally, removing possible trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

- get all the digits in a string using regex `[\d]+`
- cast the match to integer
- use modulo(%) operator to get the digits from the number
- finally use your dictionary to get the number in word

Alternate solution

- use `re.findall(r'[\d]', my_string)`
- this will give you all possible digits
- next just use `my_string.replace(digit, f' {conversion_dict[digit]} ' )`

Comment: @Ijnath but that will wrongly process the alphanumeric words
for example if 44F5 was a word in the sentence the above process will only peak 445 and convert it to FOUR FOUR FIVE , but actually should have been FOUR FOUR F FIVE

Comment: Sure, there is an alternate solution, let me edit the main solution with that

Comment: Ijnath , I did it like this 

list(filter(lambda w: w.isdigit() or w.isalnum() and not w.isalpha(), s.strip().split()))

this returns a list of numeric and alphanumeric entities where s is the sentence